# custom page under single post type name not working

Tags: php

post type page: https://prnt.sc/HMNzcsQuqqIC
single-post type :image link: https://prnt.sc/I3COwDGVwO6O

I created a custom post type page {post type name= services} and a single post page {single-services}. all are working but the title problem I am facing here. When I post on the custom post page is that working. On the other side when I click the post link on the title. that is a show similar to all posts. But I want when I click a post link only to show this post. Please help

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="services_wrapper">
              <?php
              $customservice = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'services',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order' => 'ASC'
                ));
                while ( $customservice->have_posts() ) : $customservice->the_post();?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="services-item">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title();?></h2> </a>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>    
               <?php endwhile;?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>enter code here
```

Comment: Custom post tyle page under single page not working problem solve. use upper code on custom post page or template.

after use under code on single.php file 

<?php
    if(have_posts()){ the_post(); rewind_posts();}
?>
<?php if('services'==get_post_type()){?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-services.php');?>

<?php 
}else{
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-blog.php');
}?>

Comment: explain this formate code:  
I created a single blog page here, to show the posts that are made regularly. And I have taken the single service page to show custom posts, you can show another custom in the same way.

I used this code to show single post on single{post type}

Comment: <?php 
    if(have_posts()):
     while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
      <article class="wrapper-article">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title();?></h2> </a>
          <figure>
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></a> 
        </figure>
           <?php the_content();?>
          </article>                
        <?php endwhile;
           else:
            echo '<p>No content found</p>';
                    endif;
           ?>